# Create empty boxed slice

Tags: rust, allocation

What is the most canonical way to create `Box<[T]>` which is empty? Such box should effectively just become a dangling pointer with zero length and nothing should be allocated, right?

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ that you want a `Box<[T]>`? What would it be used for?

Comment: `Box::new([])`. Don’t overcomplicate this.

Comment: @user3840170 that creates a `Box<[T;0]>` (a box to an empty array) though, not a `Box<[T]>` (a boxed slice).

Comment: But that’s easily fixed by `CoerceUnsized`.

Comment: An empty slice would still need space to indicate it's empty. But I don't think it's allocate something. It's probably depend on the behaviour of the global allocator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most canonical way to create Box<[T]> which is empty?

`Box::from()` or `slice::into()`.

> Such box should effectively just become a dangling pointer with zero length and nothing should be allocated, right?

No. `[T]` is a slice, which is a DST. In such a case, `Box` would be a fat pointer, with box itself holding the metadata (the size of the slice):

```rust
let ar = [0;5];
let boxed: Box<[_]> = ar[..].into();
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&boxed));
```

will print 16, even if the underlying slice is empty (e.g. `ar[..0]`).

If the value is a ZST however (e.g. `Box<[_;0]>`) then there is indeed a special case to not allocate: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9c09c1f7cfcf9de0522bcd1cfda32b552195c464/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs#L163

Comment: ZST is zero-sized type. What is DST?

Comment: @hkBst Dynamically-sized type.

Comment: But if the slice is empty there will be no allocation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca45f1304c1344f969982aa00c5fda1a.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman generally it's implemented behaviour, for example ask 0 bytes to `malloc()` could return a valid pointer or `NULL` it's unclear thus I think any good allocator should return a valid pointer that doesn't allocated anything.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman for example https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html#safety-1

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/alloc/alloc.rs.html#166 handle zero size request, trait used https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html.